# Struggling with a datetime issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

bear with me as I am still quite the newbie.  I am simply trying to subtract 2 dates to get the number of days in between and is not quite working out correctly.  Here is part of my code giving me problems and as you can see i add extra lines just to help me make sure things are going right.

```
days = date2 - date1
        print(type(days))  # // for debugging
        print(days)  # // for debugging
        list3.append(days)
        print(type(list3))  # // for debugging
        print(list3)  # // for debugging
        print('The number of days between the two dates is', days)
```

and here is the result.

```
<class 'datetime.date'>
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>  ***<--needs to be string i think***
365 days, 0:00:00             ***<-- want just to print 365***
<class 'list'>
[datetime.timedelta(days=365)]   ***<-- needs to be a normal list format i think [365, 133] etc..*** 
The number of days between the two dates is 365 days, 0:00:00  ***<-- don't need time formatting***
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you initialized `date1` and `date2`.

Comment: `print(days.days)` formats the timedelta as days **without** time.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Please correct your code styling and supply date1 and date2 initialization

Comment: try `list3.append(days.days)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```py
import pandas as pd
date1 = '2010-09-01'
date2 = '2010-10-22'
mydates = pd.date_range(date1, date2).tolist() # Makes a list with the days in between the two dates
ndays = len(mydates)

print('The number of days between the two dates is', int(ndays), 'days')
```

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting "import pandas as pd" and how you get pandas you ask then "pip3 install pandas"

Comment: Then add that to your answer. Your answer is incomplete, non-running code.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I assumed you were working with dataframe. The answer provided by @d-coder should do the same!
I completed the code so it is a bit easier to follow. Sorry, it's my first day here! :(

Comment: When a question is asked without involving external imports, do not use them in your answer. You can suggest it as an alternative of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this and let me know if this works out for you.

```
from datetime import date

d0 = date(2020, 8, 18)
d1 = date(2020, 9, 26)
delta = d1 - d0
print(delta.days) # // for debugging obv :P
list3.append(delta.days) ## // notice .days here 
print(list3)  # // for debugging obv :P
```

A lot of assumptions have gone through while answering this question!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it in the following way. Here  I am assuming that your input of dates will be in string format (You haven't given any info on this in your question).

```
from datetime import datetime 

def time_diff(a,b):
    FMT= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    t_delta = datetime.strptime(a,FMT)-datetime.strptime(b,FMT)
    return t_delta
```

You can use the above program in the following way.

```
time_diff("2019-10-05 00:00:00","2019-10-10 00:12:00")
```

this will return

```
datetime.timedelta(days=-6,seconds = 85680)
```

You can obtain the exact number of `days` using `.days` method of the above object.

If your datetime input is in a different format, you can edit `FMT` variable as explained in [here](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/time.html).